# How to reduce duplicate AJAX requests using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have one requirement,at the time popup loading two requests are sending.But I want only one request.I tried this following code. Please share me some ideas.

```
 $("#product_accordion").find(".pin").click(function(){
                 $.ajax({
                    dataType:"text",
                    url:"/aaa/aaa/pin.do?action=form",
                    type:"POST",                    
                    success: function(result){                  
                        if(result.indexOf('epayPinNumber') != -1){
                            $('.overlayBorder').css({"width":610,"height":192});
                            $('.overlayBorderInner').css({"padding-top":0,"padding-left":20,"width":440});
                            displayOverlay('/aaa/aaa/pin.do?action=form','block','552','192','100%','1000','#000000',($(window).width() - $('.overlayBorder').width()) / 2,'50');
                        }else{                      
                            $('.overlayBorder').css({"width":628,"height":120});
                            $('.overlayBorderInner').css({"padding-top":0,"padding-left":20,"width":440});
                            displayOverlay('/aaa/aaa/pin.do?action=form','block','573','120','100%','1000','#000000',($(window).width() - $('.overlayBorder').width()) / 2,'50');
                        }                                                               
                    }
                });
                return false;
          });
```

Comment: so you say you click once and two requests are performed ? are you sure not to click ontwo elements with class ".pin" at the same time, so it gets triggered twice ?

Comment: or is your second request inside the function  displayOverlay() that is called after the first sucess ?

Comment: >>so you say you click once and two requests are performed ?Yes..have once button,once we click on that button for displaying popup, at that time only sending two requests.

Comment: and if you comment out the lines that call  displayOverlay() , are there still two requests performed ?

Comment: No, at that time I am not getting popup.

Answer (score 0):

use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to stop default action  triggered.

```
$("#product_accordion").find(".pin").click(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $.ajax({
                    dataType:"text",
                    url:"/aaa/aaa/pin.do?action=form",
                    type:"POST",                    
                    success: function(result){                  
                        if(result.indexOf('epayPinNumber') != -1){
                            $('.overlayBorder').css({"width":610,"height":192});
                            $('.overlayBorderInner').css({"padding-top":0,"padding-left":20,"width":440});
                            displayOverlay('/aaa/aaa/pin.do?action=form','block','552','192','100%','1000','#000000',($(window).width()
- $('.overlayBorder').width()) / 2,'50');
                        }else{                      
                            $('.overlayBorder').css({"width":628,"height":120});
                            $('.overlayBorderInner').css({"padding-top":0,"padding-left":20,"width":440});
                            displayOverlay('/aaa/aaa/pin.do?action=form','block','573','120','100%','1000','#000000',($(window).width()
- $('.overlayBorder').width()) / 2,'50');
                        }                                                               
                    }
                });
                return false;
          });
```

Comment: No Luck, again one get request and one post request sending (total 2 requests)

Comment: I'm guessing there is another click function defined in the page which is firing the get ajax request.

Comment: As per my knowledge initially I passing 'UR'L and also 'displayOverlay' sending same request, I think this is the case getting two requests.I tried to remove URL and kept only in displayOverlay function, but it enters to the else case.